# Detect double tap on notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I've created a local custom notification using Remote View. Currently I'm using pending intent to open activity. 
But I want to open it only on double tap of notification. I know there is no click listener for notification. Still, is there any way to do it? Thanks in advance.